# return base64 string from graphql api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, graphql

I have a graphql api and I want to return a pdf file.
In the first step, I will need to define the query. For that query will a string type returned value can work?

```
field :pdf, String
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a PDF file as a String could work, if encoded as Base64.

This pdf field would be defined in your schema as a nullable String,
e.g. in your own custom type:

```
type YourType { 
    pdf: String 
}
```

or as a nullable String-based return value of your own GraphQL query:

```
Query { 
    yourQuery(someParam: String!): String 
}
```

Be aware of providing a serverside query/field resolver (a custom data fetcher), 
that takes your PDF file, creates a Base64-encoded String of it and returns that String.

On your frontend, this encoded String obviously needs to be decoded again...